# What is the best way to customize Joomla urls?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I have a big joomla site and I want to customize its links to be as SEF as possible. I need an alias for each individual article and custom component item. Is it better to use the router.php class in each component or to assign a hidden menu item for each one from the perspective of the load on the server and the clean xml generated sitemaps?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand your question i would like to suggest you to use [sh404SEF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134). It rewrites Joomla URL to user-friendly format (SEF URL or URL rewriting):

**For Example:**

`mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&Itemid=69&id=34...` becomes

`mysite.com/en/sh404SEF-and-url-rewriting/list-of-available-plugins.html`.

It is also a security component. Page title and meta tags manager for every page. With or without .htaccess file. Joomfish compatible. Caching system for high speed and very small DB queries overhead.

Or as you say you can also use router.php class in each of your component to make sef url. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Does sh404SEF recognize custom components? I have components that I have built and I wonder if it can handle them. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Manhal You have to make a individual file for each of the component in it then it will automatically recognize the custom component.

Comment: So you think that creating a menu item for each item is a bad idea?

Comment: @Manhal No it's not and bad idea to have no. of menu link in the site it will be beneficial for SEO purpose.

Comment: So which scenario you think is the best. I don't want my site to be slow because I have chosen the wrong choice

Comment: Its better to have SH404 in my opinion. Using custom components shouldn't be an issue - however make sure your custom components are compatible. 99% of components will be - all the big ones certainly are. If you're unsure ask the extension developer though before you buy SH404

Comment: @Manhal Go for sh404. Your custom components should be handled fine (they usually are, if your router.php is ok you also have the option to use your own, so it's not mandatory to write your own sh404 router too.